# Why wont my queue implementation work

Tags: java, linked-list, queue

Im trying to make a linked list implementation of a queue in java we are working from a basic IQueue interface then we have a list element class which defines the elements in the list/queue then we also have a MyQueue class which the bulk of the information is stored in. I will provide all of the code below. I have also written a test.java main class to run it all and see if it is working then when I compiled it and ran it I got some errors which will also be shown.

Interface:

```
/**
* An interface for a generic queue
*/
public interface IQueue<E> {

    // Add an element to the (end of) queue.
    public void enqueue(E element);

    // Remove and return element from the (start of) queue.
    public E dequeue();

    // Returns true when the queue has no elements, false otherwise.
    public boolean isEmpty();

}
```

List element:

```
public class ListElement<E> {

    private final E value;
    private ListElement<E> next;
    private ListElement<E> prev;

    public ListElement(E value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public E getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public ListElement<E> getNext() {
        return this.next;
    }

    public ListElement<E> getPrev() {
        return this.prev;
    }

    public void setNext(ListElement<E> e) {
        this.next = e;
    }

    public void setPrev(ListElement<E> e) {
        this.prev = e;
    }

}
```

MyQueue.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class MyQueue<E> implements IQueue<E> {

    private ListElement<E> head;
    private ListElement<E> tail;

    public MyQueue() {
        head = null;
        tail = null;
    }

    // INCOMPLETE.
    public E modifyHead(E newhead) {
        ListElement<E> update_head = new ListElement(newhead);
        ListElement<E> oldhead = new ListElement(head);
        head = update_head;
        // Modifies the head of the queue to contain newhead.
        // Returns the old value in the head.
        return oldhead.getValue();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (head == null);
    }

    public E dequeue() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        ListElement<E> tmp = head;
        head = tmp.getNext();

        if (head == null) {
            tail = null;
        }

        return tmp.getValue();
    }

    public void enqueue(E value) {
        ListElement<E> tmp = new ListElement(value);

        if (isEmpty()) {
            tail = head = tmp;
        } else {
            tail.setNext(tmp);
            tail = tmp;
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
        while (head.getNext() != null){
            a.add(head.getNext());
        }
        return a.toString();
    }
}
```

Test.java:

```
public class test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        MyQueue test = new MyQueue();
        test.MyQueue();
        test.enqueue("Kieran");
        test.enqueue("Lavelle");
        test.toString();
        test.modifyHead("Replacement Head");
        test.toString();
    }
}
```

Sorry for that big bulk of code but I feel it is all needed to help the issue be worked out. Thanks in advance and here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test/java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.java
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Bit of an accident I ran it wrong. New error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2760)
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2734)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacity(ArrayList.java:167)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:351)
    at MyQueue.toString(MyQueue.java:55)
    at test.main(test.java:6)
```

Comment: how do you start your code? it looks like it is lacking permissions or acces at some point.

Comment: What did you do that caused that exception to show up ? i.e. how are you compiling and running this code ?

Comment: Looks like you classpath is incorrect.

Comment: You dont need to run `java test.java`, use `java -cp . test`(without .java extension) if you haven't compiled your code, compile it with `javac test.java` (and others)

Comment: public class test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        MyQueue test = new MyQueue();
        test.MyQueue(); I don't know what is happening here, but looks like you are calling the constructor of MyQueue? Also using test without a capital should be avoided.

Comment: Sorry guys part of my issue was I accidentally called it wrong e.g adding the extension .java when there is no need. Just a total accident. And there was no need for me to call test.MyQueue(); it was just an attempt to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In toString method, you don't move from head, and without that head will always have next element

```
while (head.getNext() != null){
     a.add(head.getNext());
}
```

So you have inifinite loop.

Also, when adding new element, not only must current tail reference new element with 'next', new element must reference tail with 'prev'.

In toString you should something like this

```
ListElement<E> item = head;
a.add(item);
while (item.getNext() != null){
     a.add(item.getNext());
     item = item.getNext();
}
```

And when adding element something like this

```
tail.setNext(tmp);
tmp.setPrev(tail);
tail = tmp;
```

Comment: The error I am getting is some type of memory error so I though the error would be there, so what should I do to solve this? Sorry im not quite sure? OHH I may see the issue.